# What's wrong with this arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

```
=arrayformula(if(LEN(A:A),if(ROW(A:A)=1,"Outstanding amount Payment",
 sum(QUERY(daily_fee_collection!A:D,"select D where B="&A:A&"",-1)))))
```

I am trying to cross-check for payments made in the sheet containing transaction records with the sheet containing the voucher no. against which the purchase was made.

The formula only works if I change A:A in the query string

```
"select D where B="&A:A&"
```

to

```
A2:D
```

Answer (score -1):

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY('daily cash'!A2:D, 
 "select A,C, sum(D) group by A,C label sum(D)''"), 3, 0)), )
```

[image: 9]

Comment: I have already tried this. It picks only the data of cell A1 and that same A1 cell data I used throughout the columns

Comment: please have a look on this sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yj8sMyO4HgIIGvStIdP3z73CbowPfvgN5YvlAgA85tg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @tinkershukla answer updated - problem solved